# I've got $R=\{a/b \in\Bbb Q\mid b\, \text{ is odd }\}$ and I have to prove that $R$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Q,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers

I've got $R=\{a/b \in\Bbb Q\mid b\, {\rm is}\, {\rm odd }\}$ and I have to prove that $R$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Q,+)$

---

I've taken two element from $R$, which are: $a=c/d$ and $b=e/f$ (with $d$ and $f$ odd) and I see that $a+(-b)=(cf-ed)/(df)$ is into $R$ owing to the fact that it is in $\Bbb Q$ and $df$ is odd. But to prove that $R$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb  Q,+)$ **I also need to check that $R$ is not empty**. How can I prove that? Is it trivial to say that $1$ is into $R$, for example?

Comment: Dear friend can you try formatting the question with LaTeX? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to prove something is "NOT TRUE", it is usually sufficient to give one counter-example. As you said $1\ \epsilon\ R$ is one such example which is sufficient.

In logic:

Let there be a statement $P:= R$ is empty.

Then it's negation $\lnot P = R$ is not empty.

So, all you have to do is find a [counter-example](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sat-counter-examples/) to disprove $P$, that will simultaneously prove $\lnot P$.

So, yes, it is enough to state that $1\ \epsilon\ R$.

Comment: And how can I prove that 1 is in R? Is it enough to say that: If for example b is 1 and a is also 1, 1/1 is in Q and b=1 is odd. Because of that 1 is in R?

Comment: YES! That's Correct!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The number $1$ is odd.${}$

Comment: What do you want to say with that?

Comment: Well, @Maialen, $$\frac{1}{1}=1.$$

Comment: Do you mean that, it is enough to say that: If for example b is 1 and a is also 1, 1/1 is in Q and b=1 is odd. Because of that 1 is in R?

Comment: Yes, @Maialen.${}$

Comment: @Maialen, if $1$ makes you doubtful, just take $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try proving that the neutral element is in R .That would be the best approach to show that a group is not empty.

Comment: Is it enough to say that: We know that the neutral element is 0, and a/b is going to be 0 if a is 0 (if we divide 0 with any odd number is going to be 0). So 0/b is going to be in Q and b is going to be odd. Because of that, 0 is in R.